# Should I use Laravel or other PHP MVC framework for single page application?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, single-page-application

What is the benefits of using Laravel or other PHP MVC framework for single page application?

I used to work with Laravel but now I only need a single page application, should I use laravel for it or any other MVC framework, or any kind of SPA framework?

Or should I go with a bunch of homemade php scripts instead?

P.S.
The single-page-app is going to be a big one.

Comment: It seems you didn't work enough with Laravel (or with any framework). Keep using it until you find the answer to this question. Or try another approach, you'll probably find the answer earlier this way. *(I'm not suggesting that the answer is to use Laravel, I just want to say that only you can tell what's better for you and the only way to know is to keep trying.)*

Comment: I know how to use it, I don't know how to advocate the use of it to those who never used it and who don't see why it is beneficial. They practically have solved all the issues that framework is solving, however I feel like it is better to use framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between a classical site and a single-page-app is mostly on the frontend and, if done correctly, wouldn't affect your backend code.

In your place, I would worry more about whether to use a frontend framework (like Angular or React) or stick with custom-made native JS (and no, "just use jQuery" would not fly in this case).

---

As for "benefits of a framework", that depends on how skilled you actually are.

In general, a php framework comes with two things: strongly implied architecture and a set of utility packages (orm, templating, routing). Therefore, it's most beneficial, if you are quite good at basic PHP, but completely suck at application architecture and/or OOP in general.

But, if you are actually good at those latter two, then framework becomes nothing more than "collateralized debt obligation" of technical debt. You can get your MVP up an running in couple hours, but for next 3 months you suffer, while fighting against framework's built-in assumptions and constraints.

---

If you can, I would recommend to instead assemble your dependencies (previously mentioned: templating, routing, etc.) from separate composer packages, where each of those packages solve one specific problem and does nothing else. But that will requite you to actually do the "architecture" part yourself.

<kbd>my two cents</kbd>

Comment: I'm thinking that out of MVC, I don't need much. I don't need views and controllers along with routing. Models is not needed as well, because we rather shift logic to Postgres SQL server, creating functions and triggers there. which is basically defeat the MVC necessity. However some packages are still needed like composer with phpunit and carbon and some api wrappers, like mailchimp and similar.

Comment: maybe lumen would be beneficial? I there are nice concept of middleware there that may be useful, and it comes with bugsnag integration and contracts for writing logs, and nice packages like .env, and configs,  collections and helper functions...

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev composer, postgreSQL, phpunit and API wrappers have nothing to do with MVC. Instead it is an specific architectural solution, that implements *"Separation of Concerns"* by  adding additional constrains to what code should go in which layer.